# Various text contents to be vertically aligned within a div

Tags: html, css

For header banners on certain pages, I need to create a dark grey transparent overlay with text inside. While I am able to create the box with same height and width on all the pages, due to variations in text content I am unable to get the text aligned vertically within the `<div>`.

I have tried vertical-align, various positions, and the only one that seems to work is the code provided - however it brings the text area to be very narrow and the client wants it wider.

```css
.grey-backing {
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 76, 0.9);
  height: 325px;
  position: relative;
}

.grey-backing-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="grey-backing">
  <div class="grey-backing-center">
    <h1 style="color: #fff;"><b>HEADING 1</b></h1>
    <hr class="uk-divider-icon uk-width-medium uk-margin-auto">
    <h4 style="color: #fff; margin-top: 15px;">Company is a unique, state-of-the-art platform that visualizes solutions and integrates the best features of strategy design, performance management, social networking and collaboration software capabilities.</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grey-backing">
  <div class="grey-backing-center">
    <h1 style="color: #fff;"><strong>CASE STUDY</strong></h1>
    <hr class="uk-divider-icon uk-width-medium uk-margin-auto">
    <h3 style="margin-top: 15px; color: #fff;"><b>A GLOBAL PHARMACEUTICAL</b></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The width of the box would be 100% width of the page, but the required text is showing in 50% of that rather than in say 75% of the box. I generally make the adjustments with 
 as it varies. But if the text was vertically aligned it would help solve the problem.

margin: auto; still has the content aligned to the top rather than vertically aligned. I am out of options to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think more clarification might be needed as to what exactly you are looking for. But if you want the text wrapper to be a certain width of the page, you can set that width specifically:
`.grey-backing-center { width: 75%; }`

The text wrapper seems to be vertically aligned correctly based on what I see in the example snippets.

Comment: Thank you so much! The width:75% solved the problem. Greatly appreciated